# nginx serve both django static files and react static files

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx

Im recently trying to impement nginx to link up my django based backend and react based frontend. Here is my nginx config file:

```
upstream api {
server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location /api/ {
        uwsgi_pass backend:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        uwsgi_pass backend:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }


    # ignore cache frontend
    location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {    
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';    
        expires off;    
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    location / {
      root /var/www/frontend;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
    
    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
    
}
```

However, the issue is that my manage.py collect static will place the django static files into `/vol/static` however, my react build is in `/var/www/frontend/` therefore when I try accessing the default / url, it returns a blank page. However, if i remove the

```
location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
```

It will serve my my django admin page without any css. How do i resolve this easily without putting both static files in the same directory?

Comment: why do both have same alias if they are not on same location?

Comment: hey @iklinac i was refering to the react's index.html not restframework